# “`(a \, b)” is equivalent to “`(a . ,b)”

Tags: backquote

I found this when playing at `*ielm*`:

```lisp
ELISP> `(emacs-version \, emacs-version)
(emacs-version . "28.2")

ELISP> `(emacs-version . ,emacs-version)
(emacs-version . "28.2")

ELISP>
```

I have never heard of this usage of `\,`, is it a feature or bug?

---

OP reported this as Emacs [bug #61281](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=61281).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. It's certainly not documented, as far as I can tell. And I haven't seen it in other Lisps.

And I see the same behavior back through Emacs 20! That's a long way back.

If you don't get a contrary opinion with an explanation then consider doing `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Emacs developers will tell you whether it's a bug.

---

I'd actually expect the behavior of `\,` within a backquoted list to just insert the symbol `,`. In other words, I'd expect  `` `(a \, 42) `` to return this list of three elements: `(a \, 42)`.

---

The code in `backquote.el` that causes this is this bit of the definition of function `backquote-process`: `(eq (car s) backquote-unquote-symbol)`, where `backquote-unquote-symbol` is the symbol `\,`.

Comment: An email is sent to bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org to report the case :-)