# Backquote List & Evaluate Vector or conversely

Tags: backquote

`C-h f backquote`:

> The whole structure acts as if it were quoted except for certain places where expressions are evaluated and inserted or **spliced in**.
>
> Vectors work just like lists.

What does the '**spliced in**' mean?

```lisp
;; I expect for (1 2 3)
`(1 ,@[2] 3)  ; => (1 2 3), looks fine

;; I expect for [1 2 3]
`[1 ,@'(2) 3]  ; => [1 2 3], fine too
```

whereas

```lisp
`(,@[])   ; => [], what?
`[,@'()]  ; => [(\,@ 'nil)], what's this?
```

Comment: The weird `\,` also appears in the [question: \`(a \, b) is equivalent to \`(a . ,b)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75700)

Comment: See `C-h i g (elisp)Backquote` on the meaning of "splice".

Comment: @phils: According to documentation, `(backquote [,@'()])` should return `[]` (?)

Comment: See my answer, but I suspect the fact that vectors are self-quoting will be the reason for that one.  I don't see any documentation which explicitly suggests you could expect to get an empty vector, as all of the examples I can see are list-based.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether or to what extent "Vectors work just like lists" is intended to mean "you can mix and match vectors and lists", but the behaviour does look inconsistent.  I suggest you report it as a bug, even if just to clarify the documentation.

> ```
> `(,@[])   ; => [], what?
> ```

You're splicing a vector value into an empty list value, and evidentially the vector "wins" that conflict.  Note that the fact that it's an empty vector is not relevant -- when you do this, you just get the vector as a result.

> ```
> `[,@'()]  ; => [(\,@ 'nil)], what's this?
> ```

The `\,@` comes from the output of the lisp reader.  backquote.el comments:

```
When the Lisp reader sees `(...), it generates (\` (...)).
When it sees ,... inside such a backquote form, it generates (\, ...).
For ,@... it generates (\,@ ...).
```

This is also the case outside of a list:

```
(read ",@foo")
=> (\,@ foo)
```

And as you'll know, `()` and `nil` are the same thing, hence:

```
(read "[,@'()]")
=> [(\,@ 'nil)]
```

The question is therefore "why is the verbatim value from the lisp reader ending up in the vector" and I strongly suspect the answer is simply that vectors are self-quoting, and that it's therefore expected behaviour.

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Vectors` on this point:

> A vector, like a string or a number, is considered a constant for
> evaluation: the result of evaluating it is the same vector.  This does
> not evaluate or even examine the elements of the vector.  *Note
> Self-Evaluating Forms::

Comment: If "*the answer is simply that vectors are self-quoting*" is the reason, why `(backquote [1 ,@'(2) 3])` doesn't return `[1 (\,@ '(2)) 3]`?

Comment: What does "*the vector 'wins' that conflict*" mean? `(backquote (1 ,@[2]))` even provides a more weird result -- `(1 . [2])`. It doesn't win; it just ends the game.

Comment: I'm guessing.  As I said up front, I suggest that you report this.  It might be a bug or it might just be undefined behaviour.

Comment: "*I suggest that you report this.*" -- +1; will do.